# Capture screenshot of fullscreen DX11 program using SharpDX and EasyHook

Tags: c#, directx-11, sharpdx, easyhook

Before anybody mentions it, I refered to [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/274461/Very-fast-screen-capture-using-DirectX-in-Csharp) link to find out how I needed to copy the backbuffer to a bitmap.

**Current situation**

- I am injected to the target process
- Target process' FeatureLevel = Level_11_0
- Target SwapChain is being made with DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_FLAG_ALLOW_MODE_SWITCH flag.
- SwapChain::Present function is hooked.
- Screenshot turns out black and target process crashes. without screenshot process runs fine.

**Desired situation**

Make the screenshot properly and let the target process continue with its normal execution.

**Code**

NOTE Hook class is the same as in the link. I only added an UnmodifiableHook version of it which does what its name says. I left out all unimportant bits.

*TestSwapChainHook.cs*

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Test
{
    public sealed class TestSwapChainHook : IDisposable
    {
        private enum IDXGISwapChainVirtualTable
        {
            QueryInterface = 0,
            AddRef = 1,
            Release = 2,
            SetPrivateData = 3,
            SetPrivateDataInterface = 4,
            GetPrivateData = 5,
            GetParent = 6,
            GetDevice = 7,
            Present = 8,
            GetBuffer = 9,
            SetFullscreenState = 10,
            GetFullscreenState = 11,
            GetDesc = 12,
            ResizeBuffers = 13,
            ResizeTarget = 14,
            GetContainingOutput = 15,
            GetFrameStatistics = 16,
            GetLastPresentCount = 17,
        }

        public static readonly int VIRTUAL_METHOD_COUNT_LEVEL_DEFAULT = 18;

        private static IntPtr[] SWAP_CHAIN_VIRTUAL_TABLE_ADDRESSES;

        [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
        public delegate int DXGISwapChainPresentDelegate(IntPtr thisPtr, uint syncInterval, SharpDX.DXGI.PresentFlags flags);

        public delegate int DXGISwapChainPresentHookDelegate(UnmodifiableHook<DXGISwapChainPresentDelegate> hook, IntPtr thisPtr, uint syncInterval, SharpDX.DXGI.PresentFlags flags);

        private DXGISwapChainPresentHookDelegate _present;
        private Hook<DXGISwapChainPresentDelegate> presentHook;

        static TestSwapChainHook()
        {
            SharpDX.DXGI.Rational rational = new SharpDX.DXGI.Rational(60, 1);
            SharpDX.DXGI.ModeDescription modeDescription = new SharpDX.DXGI.ModeDescription(100, 100, rational, SharpDX.DXGI.Format.R8G8B8A8_UNorm);
            SharpDX.DXGI.SampleDescription sampleDescription = new SharpDX.DXGI.SampleDescription(1, 0);

            using (SharpDX.Windows.RenderForm renderForm = new SharpDX.Windows.RenderForm())
            {
                SharpDX.DXGI.SwapChainDescription swapChainDescription = new SharpDX.DXGI.SwapChainDescription();
                swapChainDescription.BufferCount = 1;
                swapChainDescription.Flags = SharpDX.DXGI.SwapChainFlags.None;
                swapChainDescription.IsWindowed = true;
                swapChainDescription.ModeDescription = modeDescription;
                swapChainDescription.OutputHandle = renderForm.Handle;
                swapChainDescription.SampleDescription = sampleDescription;
                swapChainDescription.SwapEffect = SharpDX.DXGI.SwapEffect.Discard;
                swapChainDescription.Usage = SharpDX.DXGI.Usage.RenderTargetOutput;

                SharpDX.Direct3D11.Device device = null;
                SharpDX.DXGI.SwapChain swapChain = null;
                SharpDX.Direct3D11.Device.CreateWithSwapChain(SharpDX.Direct3D.DriverType.Hardware, SharpDX.Direct3D11.DeviceCreationFlags.BgraSupport, swapChainDescription, out device, out swapChain);
                try
                {
                    IntPtr swapChainVirtualTable = Marshal.ReadIntPtr(swapChain.NativePointer);

                    SWAP_CHAIN_VIRTUAL_TABLE_ADDRESSES = new IntPtr[VIRTUAL_METHOD_COUNT_LEVEL_DEFAULT];
                    for (int x = 0; x < VIRTUAL_METHOD_COUNT_LEVEL_DEFAULT; x++)
                    {
                        SWAP_CHAIN_VIRTUAL_TABLE_ADDRESSES[x] = Marshal.ReadIntPtr(swapChainVirtualTable, x * IntPtr.Size);
                    }

                    device.Dispose();
                    swapChain.Dispose();
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    if (device != null)
                    {
                        device.Dispose();
                    }

                    if (swapChain != null)
                    {
                        swapChain.Dispose();
                    }

                    throw;
                }
            }
        }

        public TestSwapChainHook()
        {
            this._present = null;

            this.presentHook = new Hook<DXGISwapChainPresentDelegate>(
                        SWAP_CHAIN_VIRTUAL_TABLE_ADDRESSES[(int)IDXGISwapChainVirtualTable.Present],
                        new DXGISwapChainPresentDelegate(hookPresent),
                        this);
        }

        public void activate()
        {
            this.presentHook.activate();
        }

        public void deactivate()
        {
            this.presentHook.deactivate();
        }

        private int hookPresent(IntPtr thisPtr, uint syncInterval, SharpDX.DXGI.PresentFlags flags)
        {
            lock (this.presentHook)
            {
                if (this._present == null)
                {
                    return this.presentHook.original(thisPtr, syncInterval, flags);
                }
                else
                {
                    return this._present(new UnmodifiableHook<DXGISwapChainPresentDelegate>(this.presentHook), thisPtr, syncInterval, flags);
                }
            }
        }

        public DXGISwapChainPresentHookDelegate present
        {
            get
            {
                lock (this.presentHook)
                {
                    return this._present;
                }
            }
            set
            {
                lock (this.presentHook)
                {
                    this._present = value;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Using code**

*initialization*

```
private TestSwapChain swapChainHook;
private bool capture = false;
private object captureLock = new object();

this.swapChainHook = new TestSwapChainHook();
this.swapChainHook.present = presentHook;
this.swapChainHook.activate();
```

**EDIT**

I used a different method to capture a screenshot described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16020988/how-to-create-bitmap-from-surface-sharpdx) link. However my screenshot turns out like this:

[image: Rainbow image]

Now this seems to be a problem with my conversion settings or whatever but I'm unable to find out what exactly I need to do to fix it. I know that the surface I'm converting to a bitmap uses the DXGI_FORMAT_R10G10B10A2_UNORM format (32-bits, 10 bits per color and 2 for alpha I think?). But I'm not sure how this even works in the for loops (skipping bytes and stuff). I just plain copy pasted it.

*new hook function*

```
private int presentHook(UnmodifiableHook<IDXGISwapChainHook.DXGISwapChainPresentDelegate> hook, IntPtr thisPtr, uint syncInterval, SharpDX.DXGI.PresentFlags flags)
{
    try
    {
        lock (this.captureLock)
        {
            if (this.capture)
            {
                SharpDX.DXGI.SwapChain swapChain = (SharpDX.DXGI.SwapChain)thisPtr;

                using (SharpDX.Direct3D11.Texture2D backBuffer = swapChain.GetBackBuffer<SharpDX.Direct3D11.Texture2D>(0))
                {
                    SharpDX.Direct3D11.Texture2DDescription texture2DDescription = backBuffer.Description;
                    texture2DDescription.CpuAccessFlags = SharpDX.Direct3D11.CpuAccessFlags.Read;
                    texture2DDescription.Usage = SharpDX.Direct3D11.ResourceUsage.Staging;
                    texture2DDescription.OptionFlags = SharpDX.Direct3D11.ResourceOptionFlags.None;
                    texture2DDescription.BindFlags = SharpDX.Direct3D11.BindFlags.None;

                    using (SharpDX.Direct3D11.Texture2D texture = new SharpDX.Direct3D11.Texture2D(backBuffer.Device, texture2DDescription))
                    {
                        //DXGI_FORMAT_R10G10B10A2_UNORM
                        backBuffer.Device.ImmediateContext.CopyResource(backBuffer, texture);

                        using (SharpDX.DXGI.Surface surface = texture.QueryInterface<SharpDX.DXGI.Surface>())
                        {
                            SharpDX.DataStream dataStream;
                            SharpDX.DataRectangle map = surface.Map(SharpDX.DXGI.MapFlags.Read, out dataStream);
                            try
                            {
                                byte[] pixelData = new byte[surface.Description.Width * surface.Description.Height * 4];
                                int lines = (int)(dataStream.Length / map.Pitch);
                                int dataCounter = 0;
                                int actualWidth = surface.Description.Width * 4;

                                for (int y = 0; y < lines; y++)
                                {
                                    for (int x = 0; x < map.Pitch; x++)
                                    {
                                        if (x < actualWidth)
                                        {
                                            pixelData[dataCounter++] = dataStream.Read<byte>();
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            dataStream.Read<byte>();
                                        }
                                    }
                                }

                                GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(pixelData, GCHandleType.Pinned);
                                try
                                {
                                    using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(surface.Description.Width, surface.Description.Height, map.Pitch, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb, handle.AddrOfPinnedObject()))
                                    {
                                        bitmap.Save(@"C:\Users\SOMEUSERNAME\Desktop\test.bmp");
                                    }
                                }
                                finally
                                {
                                    if (handle.IsAllocated)
                                    {
                                        handle.Free();
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            finally
                            {
                                surface.Unmap();

                                dataStream.Dispose();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                this.capture = false;
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }

    return hook.original(thisPtr, syncInterval, flags);
}
```

**Answer**

Turns out the DXGI_FORMAT_R10G10B10A2_UNORM format is in this bit format:

```
A=alpha
B=blue
G=green
R=red

AABBBBBB BBBBGGGG GGGGGGRR RRRRRRRR
```

And Format32bppArgb is in this byte order:

```
BGRA
```

So the final loop code would be:

```
while (pixelIndex < pixelData.Length)
{
    uint currentPixel = dataStream.Read<uint>();

    uint r = (currentPixel & 0x3FF);
    uint g = (currentPixel & 0xFFC00) >> 10;
    uint b = (currentPixel & 0x3FF00000) >> 20;
    uint a = (currentPixel & 0xC0000000) >> 30;

    pixelData[pixelIndex++] = (byte)(b >> 2);
    pixelData[pixelIndex++] = (byte)(g >> 2);
    pixelData[pixelIndex++] = (byte)(r >> 2);
    pixelData[pixelIndex++] = (byte)(a << 6);

    while ((pixelIndex % map.Pitch) >= actualWidth)
    {
        dataStream.Read<byte>();
        pixelIndex++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That screenshot does look like R10G10B10A2 is getting stuffed into R8G8B8A8. I haven't tested your code but we should have this bit layout

```
xxxxxxxx yyyyyyyy zzzzzzzz wwwwwwww
RRRRRRRR RRGGGGGG GGGGBBBB BBBBBBAA
```

and you can extract them as follows

```
byte x = data[ptr++];
byte y = data[ptr++];
byte z = data[ptr++];
byte w = data[ptr++];

int r = x << 2 | y >> 6;
int g = (y & 0x3F) << 4 | z >> 4;
int b = (z & 0xF) << 6 | w >> 2;
int a = w & 0x3;
```

where r, g, b now have 10 bit resolution. If you want to scale them back to bytes you can do that with (byte)(r >> 2).

**Update**

This would replace your double for loop. I have no way of testing this so I don't want to push it further, but I believe the idea is correct. The last check should skip the padding bytes in each row.

```
while(dataCounter < pixelData.Length)
{

    byte x = dataStream.Read<byte>();
    byte y = dataStream.Read<byte>();
    byte z = dataStream.Read<byte>();
    byte w = dataStream.Read<byte>();

    int r = x << 2 | y >> 6;
    int g = (y & 0x3F) << 4 | z >> 4;
    int b = (z & 0xF) << 6 | w >> 2;
    int a = w & 0x3;

    pixelData[dataCounter++] = (byte)(r >> 2);
    pixelData[dataCounter++] = (byte)(g >> 2);
    pixelData[dataCounter++] = (byte)(b >> 2);
    pixelData[dataCounter++] = (byte)(a << 6);

    while((dataCounter % map.Pitch) >= actualWidth)
    {
        dataStream.Read<byte>();
        dataCounter++;
    }

}
```

Comment: wow thanks finally somebody is able to help me. so how would i go about and loop through this? just a for loop where x < width * height of image?

Comment: not quite, our x's are different. You would loop over ptr: `for(int ptr = 0; ptr < data.Length;) {...}` If needed I can adapt your code.

Comment: I cant test today unfortunately. could you adapt my code to make sure ive got it right?

Comment: see the update. you're gonna have to do the testing though since I don't have your whole code (or Ark, for that matter).

Comment: I will try to make time to try it out tomorrow. thanks alot for your answer! I will report back  as soon as i have results.

Comment: As an afterthought, it would be easier to just read one int instead of 4 bytes.

Comment: also wouldnt shifting 2 bits to the right result in a loss (obviously) but shouldnt i for example scale it like so: (value / 1023) * 255?

Comment: yes, and that loss is unavoidable if you want to save 10 bit with 8 bit. Your calculation (value * 255 / 1023) would do the same. notice value / 1023 == 0 for integers.

Comment: for integers below 1023, I mean.

Comment: Yeah I know, but first parsing them to float and then do the calculation? I know there is always a loss but simply shifting them 2 bits to the right would be divide by 4 I think if my memory of bit shifting is correct? That seems like a quick and dirty way to scale

Comment: You can convert to float and back all you want, 8 bit is 8 bit. Change your output format if you want more precision. Regarding your (v * 255 / 1023), test it! It maps 3 to 5 input values to one output value each, so it's not consistent precision over the entire range. (v >> 2) is a consistent four-to-one mapping and the shortest code. It's quick and clean.

Comment: btw (v * 255 / 1023) is common practice for floating point values, that's where you probably got that from. for integers, it's less precise and much slower than bitshift.

Comment: I just tested it and it still comes out rainbowy. replaced my for loops with your exact code. :(

Comment: Any difference though? Any insight when debugging? Apparently one of your assumptions doesn't hold, maybe it's not R10G10B10A2. I tested the snippet I gave you and it does just what you asked it to do. Honestly I think by now you could appreciate my effort and mark it as an answer, too.

Comment: maybe you're getting BGRA instead of RGBA. Common pitfall, too.